# How to create and import the database properties in pentaho data integration tool?

Tags: pentaho

I have to configure the mysql database properties in pentaho.
Please anyone suggest me stepwise. I am new to this tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the below links.

1. http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpme_user_guide%2Fconcept_pme_setting_up_db_connection.html
2. http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/.03+Database+Connections

Its pretty straight forward.

---

For dynamically passing the db-parameters through the file in pentaho. check this link:

[In pentaho..How to pass a text file which contains all the definition of the connection parameters in the job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522140/in-pentaho-how-to-pass-a-text-file-which-contains-all-the-definition-of-the-con/27526443#27526443)

Comment: Dear Rishu ,Is it possible to configure the properties in outside instead of hard coding. i need the connection through .properties file

Comment: Please share if you have ,how to import the connection through .properties file

Comment: yes it is possible.. check the link above !! i have modified the answer.

Answer (score -1):

In the transformation UI(Spoon) , there are two tabs like View and Design.
1)Select View tab 
2)Right click on database Connections
3)Click New then dialog box appears
4)Select mysql database and Define your database connection as you needed.
5)Test the connection.

[image: I added screen shot here, fill all those details]